# Geometric interpretation of dimensional reduction of $E_8 \times E_8$ string

Tags: string-theory, compactification, algebraic-geometry

Following on from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/364777/reference-for-geometry-in-heterotic-string-compactifications). I'm trying to get a geometric picture of what happens under dimensional reduction.

Let me focus on a single $E_8$ factor, in 10 dimensions - the Lagrangian will describe the Yang-Mills field of $E_8$ and its associated gauginos, both transforming under the adjoint **248** representation of $E$. I assume I can view the gauginos as being sections of a vector bundle, called $\mathbf{V}_{248}$ over the 10d space $M_{10} = M_4 \times X$, where $X$ is a Calabi-Yau threefold. The gauge fields should come from the associated principal bundle $\mathbf{P}_{248}$ over $M_{10}$.

In order to preserve supersymmetry, it turns out the we have to satisfy the Hermitian Yang-Mills equations, which involves the construction of bundles of vector bundles over the Calabi-Yau $X$. Let me construct a slope stable (with slope $= 0$) vector bundle $V$ over $X$, with structure group $H$. This then breaks the $E_8$ group into $G \times H$, where $G$ is the commutant of $H$ in $E_8$.

How do I relate the vector bundle $V$ over $X$ to the vector bundle $\mathbf{V}_{248}$ over $M_{10}$ (I assume I can restrict $\mathbf{V}_{248}$ to $X$)? My guess is that I would have to relate the fibers of $\mathbf{V}_{248}$ to various tensor products of $V$, e.g. if $H= SU(3)$ the fiber breaks up into

27 copies of $V$ + 27 copies of $V^*$ + 1 copy of $V \otimes V^*$ + 78 copies of $\mathcal{O}_X$

Q: Is this the right interpretation? Can I see how a $G$-bundle appears over $M_4$ as a result of this?

It is not clear to me from the standard texts where the principal bundle $\mathbf{P}_{248}$ enters this picture but I feel it should since we are effectively giving gauge fields VEVs. In the literature language is used about "constructing an instanton" in relation to building a bundle on the Calabi-Yau and as far as I understand there should be a relation to principal bundles.

Q: Is the principal bundle over X relevant to this discussion? Is there any clear statement about this somewhere?